# Date pipe to hide zeros

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am wondering how can I modify/create my own pipe, so that:

1. if less than minute, show seconds
2. if less than hour, show mm:ss
3. if less than 1hr, show hh:mm:ss

I know that when I usde:

```
{{ dateObj | date:'hhmmss' }}        // output is '00:00:11' when timestamp is 11s;
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Comment: You're not using date objects for *duration* values, are you?

Comment: @deceze, I am using timestamps

Comment: A timestamp is not a timespan.

Comment: It just seems odd to me that you want to format a timestamp in a way that sounds suitable for a *duration*. "11" is not a useful timestamp, "0:00:11" is. If you're trying to use *durations* (e.g. "this action lasted 3m and 5s"), **don't use date objects and date formatting.** Because a date will not give you durations longer than 24 hours. This may or may not be a practical problem, but it's conceptually wrong and easily leads to problems eventually.

Answer (score 3):

As Angular pipe is a JS class with some decorator you still can use it directly. In your case you can implement your own pipe which will use built-in angular pipe in the way like this:

```
new DatePipe().transform(myDate, 'hhmmss');
```

So let's go:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({name: 'my-duration'})
export class MyDurationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Date): string {
    if (/* time difference is less than minute */) { // add your comparison to get minutes
      return new DatePipe().transform(value, 'ss');
    } 
    else if (/* time difference is less than hour */) { // the same for hours etc.
      return new DatePipe().transform(value, 'mm:ss');
    }
    // and so on 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as a regular Pipe.

Comment: Where does `minute` and `hour` come from in your `if`s?

Comment: Look at the comments - it's not actual code but just the idea. I don't know how exactly the author would like to pass the variable (as a Date or as timestamp).